# Qual a melhor forma de consultar dados de um usuário no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ao apresentar diversos dados de um usuário em uma view, é mais aconselhável fazer de que forma?

Opção 1 (passar os dados para a view):

```
$usuario = Auth::user();
return view('painel.usuarios.perfil', compact('usuario'));
```

Opção 2 (diretamente na view):

```
Auth::user()->name
Auth::user()->email
```

Quando falo a melhor opção estou considerando as boas praticas e principalmente a questão da performance. Considere o framework Laravel 5.3

Comment: A opção 1 está bem estranha, fiquei confuso, será que poderia melhorar

Comment: O erro foi meu, havia esquecido de substituir User::user() por Auth::user()

Comment: Você precisa que esse `$usuario` ( que é o logado ), seja em uma view ou em várias views?

Comment: Somente uma view.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é uma questão de opinião e de necessidade, mas geralmente gosto de retornar pelo controller, para não deixar chamadas de atributo muito grandes na view:

```
$usuario = Auth::user();
return view('painel.usuarios.perfil', compact('usuario'));
```

E os dados que estão em outra tabela mas dentro do usuário (*nesse exemplo*), manipulo na view, para não retornar muitas variáveis:

```
$usuario->cpf->numero;
```